# Sub query returns more than 1 rows?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

So here is my code below.

```
qry = "SELECT * FROM `tblsubjects` WHERE `GRADELEVEL` = " & lblgrade.Text & " AND `SUBJECTNAME` <> (SELECT `SUBJECTNAME` FROM `tblschedule` WHERE `SECTIONNAME` = '" & lblsect.Text & "')"
```

it came from may vb application. I think the error came from the query. t I'm  making a scheduling system. On that query, i was trying to load the subjects that has not been scheduled on that gradelevel and section on to combo box. but that error comes out when i try to add more schedule on this section.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewtva.png)
Here is my whole code on this function:

```
Private Sub subjectload()
        con = New MySqlConnection
        con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;password='';database=kccbeslis"
        If DataGridView.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Try
                con.Open()
                qry = "SELECT * FROM `tblsubjects` WHERE `GRADELEVEL` = " & lblgrade.Text & " AND `SUBJECTNAME` <> (SELECT `SUBJECTNAME` FROM `tblschedule` WHERE `SECTIONNAME` = '" & lblsect.Text & "')"
                cmd = New MySqlCommand(qry, con)
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While rdr.Read
                    Dim subname = rdr.GetString("SUBJECTNAME")
                    cbsubject.Items.Add(subname)
                End While
                con.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ErrorToString)
            End Try
        Else
            Try
                con.Open()
                qry = "SELECT * FROM `tblsubjects` WHERE `GRADELEVEL` = " & lblgrade.Text & ""
                cmd = New MySqlCommand(qry, con)
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While rdr.Read
                    Dim subname = rdr.GetString("SUBJECTNAME")
                    cbsubject.Items.Add(subname)
                End While
                con.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ErrorToString)
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

help me pls!

Comment: Most likely, you just need to replace `<>` with `NOT IN`.

Comment: Try to use TOP 1 in your sub query for MS SQL, use limit=1 for mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your sub select (SELECT subjectname FROM tblscheduler where..) has multiple schedules with the same 'sectionname' you are providing, therefore is returning more than 1 row.

Are you sure your sectionname column is unique per tblschedule entry? Try a count and group by to see if you have multiple records;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblschedule GROUP BY sectionname;
```

You could try replacing <> with NOT IN if you require multiple rows.

Comment: Thanks sire. I'll try this.

Comment: thank you sir soo much. when i replace the <> to NOT IN the error does not show up. thanks a lot for fast response on my question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Subquery `SELECT`SUBJECTNAME`FROM`tblschedule`WHERE`SECTIONNAME`= '" & lblsect.Text & "'` results more than 1 records. You are using <> instead of not in, use Not In clause and try.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's cause your subquery returning more than 1 record and `<>` operator expects scalar value and list of values. You should rather use `NOT IN` operator like

```
AND `SUBJECTNAME` NOT IN (SELECT `SUBJECTNAME` FROM `tblschedule` WHERE `SECTIONNAME` = '" & lblsect.Text & "')
```

BTW, do you know your posted code is very much vulnerable to *SQL Injection*. You should consider using parameterized queries to avoid the same.

Comment: thanks a lot sir!. ok sir i'll try to search about the parameterized queries. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use NOT IN instead of <>

qry = "SELECT * FROM tblsubjects WHERE GRADELEVEL = " & lblgrade.Text & " AND SUBJECTNAME NOT IN (SELECT SUBJECTNAME FROM tblschedule WHERE SECTIONNAME = '" & lblsect.Text & "')"

Comment: thanks for fast response sir. you guys are big help to my thesis..thank you very much.!